# using a thread to store numbers in an array

Tags: android, multithreading, arrays

So im plotting points from a constantly updating array, and want to have the array calculations done in the background while the canvas is updated with the new points. whats a good way to do this?

Comment: you can use service for doing calculation in background and then invalidate() view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a simple Runnable thread that fires a custom event whenever it updates the array (which should be a thread-safe implementation of List). Register a listener in your Activity class to update the view and you're good to go.

Comment: So i created a thread on my onclicklistener to update the array...it runs very fast! thank you. the problem was  actually how the gui was pulling values FROM the array...got that fixed and now it works.